# Intercept event outside of Reactjs with native javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to intercept an elements on click event that get's triggered by a React component and then override the functionality with native javascript.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('button');
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    });
});
```

The above code is placed after the bundled react code and it looks as if it can't find the element? Is there a way I can wait for React to be loaded? Or is there a better way I can handle this? Or can I override/attach an event to a react element? (I cant use react as it's already bundled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to figure it out using plain javascript, here's my code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById('button');
        if (el != null) {
            clearInterval(checkExist);
            el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            });
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your React app ends up being a JS file that you reference in your index.html file, that means if you reference a node element that's generated inside of it, jQuery can't see it because it was dynamically generated.

To solve this issue you can use two React concepts: lifecycle methods, and refs.

**One**, create a reference of the button you're aiming to listen globally, in the parent component of that button:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button ref={(button) => this.button = button}>
        Click this button
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Two, create a `componentDidMount` life cycle method to make use of the ref you've just created:

```
class ParentComponent {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      console.log('it works?!');
    });
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <button ref={(button) => this.button = button}>
        Click this button
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that in other lifecycle methods like `componentWillMount`, or `componetWillUpdate` refs are either not existent or are old, because the component hasn't made it's most recent render yet. So, if you want to integrate 3rd party DOM libraries, use `didMount`.